# How can I load an image and write text to it using Java?

Tags: java, image, text, merge, arrays

I've an image located at images/image.png in my java project. I want to write a method its signature is as follow

`byte[] mergeImageAndText(String imageFilePath, String text, Point textPosition);`

This method will load the image located at `imageFilePath` and at position `textPosition` of the image (left upper) I want to write the `text`, then I want to return a byte[] that represents the new image merged with text.

Comment: If you don't want to go with "plain old" Java, you could try to make use of an existing image processing library. I've used ImageMagick lightly in the past, and it seemed pretty good. Its website links to an open-source Java interface called [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html;jsessionid=62FE2FA6029938F4372483DB9F301A9C).

Comment: To be honest, Java has some good support exactly for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImagingTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://icomix.eu/gr/images/non-batman-t-shirt-gross.jpg";
        String text = "Hello Java Imaging!";
        byte[] b = mergeImageAndText(url, text, new Point(200, 200));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("so2.png");
        fos.write(b);
        fos.close();
    }

    public static byte[] mergeImageAndText(String imageFilePath,
            String text, Point textPosition) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageFilePath));
        Graphics2D g2 = im.createGraphics();
        g2.drawString(text, textPosition.x, textPosition.y);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(im, "png", baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `ImageIO` to read the image into a `BufferedImage`.

Use the `getGraphics()` method of `BufferedImage` to get the Graphics object.

Then you can use the `drawString()` method of the Graphics object.

You can use `ImageIO` to save the image.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. BTW, javadocs says it's better to use createGraphics This method returns a Graphics2D, but is here for backwards compatibility. createGraphics is more convenient, since it is declared to return a Graphics2D.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to point you in the general direction of image manipulation in Java.

To load images you can use [ImageIO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html). You can also use ImageIO to output images to different formats.

The easiest way to create an image is to use [BufferedImage](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and then paint on it via [Graphics2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html). You can use Graphics2D to paint your loaded image and then paint your text on top of it.

When you're done you use ImageIO to output the image in a suitable format (PNG, JPG, etc).

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I'm going to follow