# How to write text on an image

Tags: java, android, image, text, png

I can do this in Objective-C on the iPhone, but now I'm looking for the equivalent Android Java code. I can also do it in plain Java, but I don't know what the Android specific classes are.  I want to generate a PNG image on the fly that has some text centered in the image.

```java
public void createImage(String word, String outputFilePath){ 
    /* what do I do here? */ 
}
```

Relevant threads:

- [How to write text on image in Objective-C (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992830/how-to-write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone)
- [How can I load an image and write text to it using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540376/how-can-i-load-an-image-and-write-text-to-it-using-java)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about something like:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ... // Load your bitmap here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(10); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text here", x, y, paint);
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use graphics.

A simpler approach would be to create a `FrameLayout` with two elements- the `ImageView` for the image, and another view for whatever you want drawn on top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Of course, the thing on top of the image doesn't need to be a simple `TextView`, it can be another image, or another layout containing whatever arbitrary elements you like.

Comment: This is easiest way, and works not only with static images but also surface views or whatever else

Comment: I'll give you an upvote because I agree with you in most circumstances.  But I specifically asked a different question because I have a requirement that it needs to be embedded in the image.

Comment: where in your question did you say that it needs to be embedded? anyway.

Comment: Good point, I apologize.  I thought I did, but I should have been more explicit.

Comment: It might not have been said explicitly but I did understand it that he wants the text embedded. You can also see that from the two provided links as well. So although he was nice to give you upvote because he is afraid of confrontation he should not have.

Comment: Hi friend. This answer wasn't accepted, but clearly people find it useful. Sorry this offends you enough to spend your karma downvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

GETah's answer wasn't working for me so I tweeked it a bit, here's a Kotlin version, which works, using `TextPaint`:

```
val canvas = Canvas(bm)
val textPaint = TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG or Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG)
textPaint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
textPaint.color = Color.BLACK
textPaint.textSize = 30f
canvas.drawText("Hello", 50f, 50f, textPaint)
```