# HorizontalScrollView Adding Text to Gallery

Tags: android, text, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to add texts to the images in gallery created with HorizontalScrollView in Android. You can think what I am trying to do as captions to the images. I want text to move when image moves. Do you think it is feasible to do this? If so, can you recommend me some way ? I got help from [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html) link online to create the gallery I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing the images themselves.

[How to write text on an image in Java (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318205/how-to-write-text-on-an-image-in-java-android)

This link helped me a lot.