# want to add some text over a newly captured image in android

Tags: android, image, camera, android-canvas

This is my problem:

1. Capture an image from the camera
2. Write some text on it
3. save it into an app folder

the first point I have covered.
help me out for the remaining two points

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

1 - code to write text to bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = ... // your bitmap here
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(10); 
canvas.drawText("Some Text here", x, y, paint);
```

2 - code to save bitmap to storage

```
// Assume block needs to be inside a Try/Catch block.
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream fOut = null;

File file = new File(path, "File.jpg"); 
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
fOut.flush(); // Not really required
fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

source : [Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

[How to write text on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318205/how-to-write-text-on-an-image)

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i m  new in android, so now I don't know how to put the value of x and y in drawText() method of canvas.

Comment: actually what I want just a text box should appear on the clicked image, then user have a choice to write text on it and save it.

Comment: finally, i learn the canvas class and its clear to me and working fine